# Contradicting redirected data in LinuxShell

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I am new to shell scripting

I keyed in the Command

```
$ ls -l >out.txt
```

then I see the output

```
$ vi out.txt
```

the contents of the file were

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arun arun 0 May  5 19:55 out.txt
```

i now do this

```
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arun arun 54 May  5 19:55 out.txt
```

why is there a discrepancy in the output that i received on the terminal and the output that was saved on the file out.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran

```
ls -l >out.txt
```

the sequence of events was:

1. Open the file `out.txt` for writing. Initially, the file size is 0 bytes.
2. Run `ls -l`, which sees the empty file `out.txt`.
3. Write the output of `ls -l` to `out.txt`.

After step 3, `out.txt` is a 54-byte file, which you observe with your second invocation of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you ran `ls`, `out.txt` was empty.

The second time you ran `ls`, `out.txt` contained the results of `ls`, hence not empty.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the shell parsed the command and saw the use of stdout going to out.txt, it opened out.txt in your directory with size 0 bytes.  When you did ls -l later on in the shell, out.txt already had some content and it showed the size.

Answer (score 0):

... because your first command put data into *out.txt*.  Its size is necessarily larger after that.